# change color of the label when form is focused

Tags: html, css

I have this form :

```html
<form data-required="reference" class="tag-field reference-field">
   <label for="reference-tag-input">
      Reference:
      <input type="hidden" id="reference-tag-input" class="reference-field-tagged form-control" data-removebtn="true" name="tag-2">
      <div class="tags-container"><input type="text" class="tag-input" placeholder=""></div>
   </label>
</form>
```

And I want to colorize the lable of the form when input of the form is focused. So I used this with no luck:

```
.tag-field input.tag-input:focus label {
  color: red;
}
```

How can I change the lable color when form is focused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) selector:

```css
@supports selector(:focus-within) {
  form:focus-within label { color: red; }
}
```

```html
<form data-required="reference" class="tag-field reference-field">
   <label for="reference-tag-input">
      Reference:
      <input type="hidden" id="reference-tag-input" class="reference-field-tagged form-control" data-removebtn="true" name="tag-2">
      <div class="tags-container"><input type="text" class="tag-input" placeholder=""></div>
   </label>
</form>
```

Be aware that [IE 11 does not support `:focus-within`](https://caniuse.com/css-focus-within), so this solution must be accompanied by Javascript if you need to support that dead browser.